# Server gets a GET request with jQuery .ajax PATCH request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I searched long and wide, found quite a few answers, but no working solutions for me :(

Problem: When doing an ajax PATCH request, the server returns:
"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH."

I am using Laravel 8, and there are other routes where this works flawlessly.

Route:

```
Route::prefix('prefix1')->name('prefix1.')->middleware(['auth', 'isUserActive'])->group(function ()
{
    Route::prefix('prefix2')->name('prefix2.')->group(function ()
    {
        Route::patch('/update_field_ajax/{ID}', [RelevantController::class, 'update_field_ajax'])->name('update_field_ajax');
    }
}
```

Blade view:

```
<select id="elementID" name="elementNAME" onchange="relevantFunction()" data-update-url="{{ route('prefix1.prefix2.update_field_ajax', $ID)}}" data-field_ID="relevant_DB_field">
    <option value="0" {{ $prist_popust ? "" : "selected" }} disabled>Določite popust</option>
    <option value="0" {{ $prist_popust == "0" ? "selected" : "" }}>popust 0%</option>
    <option value="25" {{ $prist_popust == "25" ? "selected" : "" }}>popust 25%</option>
    <option value="50" {{ $prist_popust == "50" ? "selected" : "" }}>popust 50%</option>
    <option value="75" {{ $prist_popust == "75" ? "selected" : "" }}>popust 75%</option>
    <option value="100" {{ $prist_popust == "100" ? "selected" : "" }}>popust 100%</option>
</select>
```

JS code:

```
        function relevantFunction() {
            var prist_strosek = {{ $prist_strosek }};
            var prist_popust = document.getElementById('prist_popust').value;
            var field_ID = document.getElementById('prist_popust').getAttribute('data-field_ID');
            var update_url = document.getElementById('prist_popust').getAttribute('data-update-url');
            prist_strosek = prist_strosek - (prist_strosek / 100 * prist_popust);
            $('#prist_znes').html(prist_strosek + ' €');

            UpdateDBField(update_url, prist_popust, field_ID);
        }

        function UpdateDBField(update_url, field_VAL, field_ID) {
            if (update_url!="") {
                auth_check();
                $.ajax({
                    url: update_url,
                    type: 'PATCH',
                    data: {fieldId: field_ID, fieldVal: field_VAL, _token: "{{ Session::token() }}", _method: "PATCH"},
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.status == "error") {
                            alert(result.text);
                        }
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Napaka pri komunikaciji s strežnikom!');
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a difference in between this route and the routes, where it works fine?

Comment: have you seen in console, is the request going as PATCH http method?
laravel has also another way, you can add an additional query string in get request `_method=patch`

Comment: @Geshode No, at least I cannot find it.

Comment: @Girish From console: PATCH http://.../prefix1/prefix2/update_field_ajax/73464352 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Ok, please look response, there would server code syntax error, unsupported method error code is 405.

Comment: @Girish do you mean this?
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH.
http://.../prefix1/prefix2/update_field_ajax/73464352

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more troubleshooting, I now understand the error of my ways;

Pasting an URL into the browser search bar will always result in a GET request... silly me :)

The code above is working as intended - the ajax PATCH request gets forwarded to the controller, where my bug was. 
I thought the problem was in ajax/route because when I opened the POST URL in my web browser (completely forgetting that is a GET request by nature) to get details it gave me a different error - GET method is not supported for this route, which I thought was my original error.